# Postgres how to return values in between Min column and Max column

Tags: sql, postgresql

totally new in learning postgres/SQL I have a table called error_table that looks like this:

```
     id       min     max       error_percent

    10R46   1         25          9
    10R46   25        50          9
    100R91  50        100         4.5
    10R91   100       200         4.6
    10M95   200       300         5.5
```

but I am having a hard time generating a query on how to do this dynamically when my input number is 160, I would like to return the error_percent value 4.6 because 160 sits between the min column 100 and max column 200.

So far, here is what I am in my query

```
SELECT error_percent FROM error_table WHERE min <= 160
```

Now the problem is, I cannot use `max <=160`. How will I able to dynamically query the corresponding max value of returned min result and use it as my max <= returned max?

IF you have a better solution than mine, I appreciate the share.

Comment: I don't understand your question, seems like a simple `where min <= 160 and max > 160`? What exactly do you mean with "*and use it as my max <= returned max"*?

Comment: Your data is inconsistent.  Do you want two rows returned for `50`?  Or is the max not inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a range comparison:

```
SELECT error_percent
FROM error_table
WHERE min < 160 AND max >= 160;
```

This assumes that your ranges are *open* on the minimum side and *closed* on the maximum side.  If not, then the above range comparison would need to be changed.

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `where int4range(min, max, '[)') @> 160`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion mate, a build-in function for postgres